# Передать в вид laravel

Tags: laravel

Подскажите, как правильно разделить вид от контроллера в данном случае.
В представленной ниже функции выводится таблица (каледарь). Что и в каком виде должен передавать контроллер   ?

```
 public function index()
    {
        $weekdays = array('Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su');
        $months = array(1 => 'Jan.', 2 => 'Feb.', 3 => 'Mar.', 4 => 'Apr.', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'Jun.', 7 => 'Jul.', 8 => 'Aug.', 9 => 'Sep.', 10 => 'Oct.', 11 => 'Nov.', 12 => 'Dec.');
        $date = Carbon::now();
        $i = $date->copy()->yesterday();
        $end = $date->copy()->addMonth();

        //получается ~32 дня
        echo " <table>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr><th>Номера</th>";
        while($i<$end) {
            echo "<th>";
            echo $weekdays[$i->dayOfWeek] . '</br>';
            echo $i->formatLocalized('%d ');
            $i = $i->addDay();
            echo "</th>";
        }
        echo "</thead></tr>";
        $nomers = Nomer::all();
        foreach ($nomers as $nomer) {
            echo "<tr><th>" . $nomer->name . "</th>";
            $j = $date->copy()->yesterday();
            while($j < $end){
                echo "<th>";
                $bron_start= DB::table('brons')
                    ->where('nomer',$nomer->id)
                    ->where( 'start' , '<=', $j)
                    ->where('end' , '>=', $j)
                    ->get();

                if ($bron_start != null )
                echo "1";
                else echo "0";
                $j = $j->addDay();
                echo "</th>";
       }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не используйте `echo/print` в `laravel` контроллерах.
Любой вывод из контроллера происходит через `return`.
Я даже не знаю где вообще в `laravel` можно использовать `echo`. Ну если только в директивах.

В вашем случае контроллер должен возвращать View::make() или view(), что по сути то же самое, там же указывается имя шаблона и какие переменные в него отдавать.

Почитайте про шаблоны в `laravel`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ - это я уже понял ) 
вопрос стоял как передать массив в представление .